# Spotify Podcast Embed Code

Tags: embed, spotify

It appears the Spotify embed code does not work with Podcast episodes. The developer section found here - https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/ only appears to work with "tracks", but not "episode", which is how Podcasts tracks are labeled.

I tried to substitute the existing "track" from the iFrame code with "episode", but it renders a "page not found" message.

That said, how do we rectify this to include Podcast episode support in your API?

Comment: Still no solution.

Comment: There are a few Podcasts that I would like to feature some select episodes on my Blog, but nothing yet. Makes no sense why Spotify has dropped the ball on this.